# How does systemd include "dependency" target files and directories in a target "unit"?

Tags: boot, systemd

In my computers `/lib/systemd/system` directory I see a file `multiuser.target` - that file contains:

```
[Unit]
Description=Multi-User System
Documentation=man:systemd.special(7)
Requires=basic.target
Conflicts=rescue.service rescue.target
After=basic.target rescue.service rescue.target
AllowIsolate=yes
```

The line: `Requires: basic.target` which I assume means "run" the `basic.target` file.
But in that same  `/lib/systemd/system` directory there is also a `multi-user.target.wants/` sub-directory. It contains a bunch more unit files:

```
/lib/systemd/system $tree multi-user.target.wants/
multi-user.target.wants/
├── dbus.service -> ../dbus.service
├── getty.target -> ../getty.target
├── systemd-ask-password-wall.path -> ../systemd-ask-password-wall.path
├── systemd-logind.service -> ../systemd-logind.service
├── systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service -> ../systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
└── systemd-user-sessions.service -> ../systemd-user-sessions.service
```

which of these units, i.e. file: `basic.target` or all of the units in sub-directory `multi-user.wants.target` is run when `multi-user.target` is the default boot target? is it all of the above? if so, what is the order?

Comment: "if so, what is the order?" Everything at once. That's the *whole point* of systemd.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams are you poking fun at systemd, or  are you saying - yes all these "units" are run, the `basic.target` and all the units in `multi-user.targer.wants` *and* they are all launched asynchronously?

Comment: All units in a set of wants are launched asynchronously. Then, once all units in a set of wants have been launched, the wanting unit is launched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a difference between `Before`/`After` and `Wants`/`Requires`/`Requisite`: the first group indicates the *timing* of unit starts, and the latter group indicates the *dependencies*. Often, there's little difference between the two, but sometimes it's important. Reading [the documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html) is useful for more details, as I've left out stuff that you don't see as often.

As an example, let's pretend that you have some services with dependencies:

**a.service**

```
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'sleep 5;/bin/false'
RemainAfterExit=yes
```

**b.service**

```
[Unit]
After=a.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/echo B
RemainAfterExit=yes
```

**c.service**

```
[Unit]
Requires=a.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/echo C
RemainAfterExit=yes
```

**d.service**

```
[Unit]
After=a.service
Requires=a.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/echo D
RemainAfterExit=yes
```

What is loaded (and in which order) changes drastically depending on what you start:

- `a`: `a`
- `b`: `b`
- `c` (or `a`+`c`): `a` and `c` at the same time (`c` stays running even if `a` fails)
- `d` (or `a`+`d`): `a`->`c` (if `a` started successfully)
- `a`+`b`: `a`->`b` (regardless of whether `a` started)

Why all this complexity? It's to speed up unit loading. If services don't have a `Before` or `After` referring to each other, then they can be started at the same time (assuming no other units need them!)

Where do the `.target` files come in? They put units into functional groups, so that as the system is started (or stopped, etc.), the units that are needed for that phase can be started together, and units can indicate that they want to wait for another phase to be started. For example, a unit can include `After=network.target` to make sure that the network had a chance to initialize before starting, even though it's installed as part of `multi-user.target`.

If you want to view the order that units depend on each other, you can run `systemctl list-dependencies` (it won't tell you the order that they loaded, though, as that's somewhat random outside of `Before`/`After` settings.)

Comment: thanks. that explains the `Wants`, `Requires` really well and explains the dependencies directly specified in the `multiuser.target` file. Do you know how the `multi-user.target.wants` directory and all the unit files within - come into the picture?

Comment: @the_velour_fog Those are auto-generated by `systemctl` when you enable a unit: it reads the `[Install]` section (specifically, `WantedBy` and `RequiredBy`) to determine which target should have a link added to the service. All of the files in those directories should just be links to the appropriate unit file (or `/dev/null` if the service has been disabled by the admin); you shouldn't have to touch them normally.